# ng-repeat not binding event though I'm getting data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Forgive me because I'm relatively new to AngularJS.  I have a situation where I am calling to a WebApi webservice.  I have two pages, one that binds and one that doesn't, with the same code in both.  I can see that the webservice is being hit and **IS** returning data.  **Any idea what the problem could be??**

**This is the data that is being returned by the webservice:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Chester"  , "gender":"Male"   , "salary":25000},
     {"id":2,"name":"Mary" , "gender":"Female" , "salary":15000},
     {"id":3,"name":"Tim " , "gender":"Male"   , "salary":22000},
     {"id":8,"name":"Wayne", "gender":"Male"   , "salary":81231}]
```

**The code that works is as follows:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/EmployeeAngular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="initController">
        {{MadeItHereMessage}}
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The code that doesn't work is here:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/EmployeeAngular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="EmployeeApplication">

<div ng-controller="EmployeeController" ng-init="AngularInit()">
        {{Message}}
    <br/>
        {{DisplayAction}}
    <br />
        <!--The following is for listing the entire list of employees-->
        <div id="listSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='List'">
            <!--The employees data is: {{employees}}-->
    <!--<div id="listSection">-->
        <table>
            <thead>List of defined Employees</thead>
            <tr>
                <!--<td><button id="btnCreateNew" type="button" value="Create Employee" ng-click="CreateNewEmployee()"></button></td>-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-show="gotdata">

                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                                <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <!--<table id="EmployeeList">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="for employee in employees">
                                <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                                <td><button type="button" value="Details" ng-click="ShowDetails({{employee.id}})"></button></td>
                                <td><button type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee({{employee.id}})"></button></td>
                                <td><button type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="EditEmployee({{employee.id}})"></button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>-->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <!--The following is for listing the details of a single employee-->
        <!--<div id="DetailsSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Details'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td> <input id="DetailsID" value={{id}} /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsName" value={{name}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsGender" value={{gender}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsSalary" value={{salary}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolist" type="button" value="Back to List" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToDelete" type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToEdit" type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="EditEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>-->
        <!--The following is for editing a employee-->
        <!--<div id="EditSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Edit'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="ID" value={{id}} />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{name}} ng-bind="name" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{gender}} ng-bind="gender" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{salary}} ng-bind="salary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="EditUpdate" type="button" value="Update" ng-click="EditUpdate()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolistEdit" type="button" value="Back to List" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToDeleteEdit" type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>-->
        <!--The following is for verification of deletion-->
        <!--<div id="DeletionSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Delete'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Do you really want to delete {{name}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnCancelDelete" type="button" value="No"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnDeleteEmployee" type="button" value="Yes" ng-click="DoDeleteEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>-->
        <!--The following is for creation of a employee-->
        <!--<div id="CreationSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Create'">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="name" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="gender" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="salary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnCreateEmployee" type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="CreateEmployee()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolistEdit" type="button" value="Back to List" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I am getting the heading, but no actual data from the web service.**

**The angularjs javascript file is here:**

```
    var app = angular.module("EmployeeApplication", [])
.controller("EmployeeController",

    function ($scope, $http) {

        AngularInit();

        function AngularInit()
        {
            //This will be called once per form load, via the ng-load function on the div
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.gender = '';
            $scope.salary = '';
            $scope.id = '';
            $scope.DisplayAction = '';
            $scope.gotdata = false;
            DisplayList();
        }

        function GetAllEmployees($http) {
            //$scope.Message = 'NULL';
            //$scope.employees = {};
            $http.get('http://localhost:65315/api/employee').then(function (response) {
                $scope.employees = response.data;
                $scope.Message = 'OK';
                $scope.go = true;
            },
            function (err) {
                $scope.Message = 'Call failed' + err.status + '  ' + err.statusText;
                $scope.employees = {};
                $scope.gotdata = false;
            }
            );

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.gotdata = true;
            }, 1000);
        };

        function DisplayList() {
            //call the web service to get the list of people
            //set the display action so that the list will be displayed
            GetAllEmployees($http)
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'List';
        };

        function CreateNewEmployee() {
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.gender = '';
            $scope.salary = '';
            $scope.id = '';
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Create';
        };

        function ShowDetails(id) {
            //call the web service to get the details of the person
            //Set the $scope.CurrentEmployee
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Details';
        };

        function CreateEmployee() {

            //perform the actual creation based on $scope.CurrentEmployee

            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };

        function DeleteEmployee(id) {
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Delete';
        };

        function DoDeleteEmployee(id) {
            //Perform actual deletion
            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };

        function EditEmployee(id) {
            //get the employee based on ID
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Edit';
        };

        function EditUpdate() {
            //perform the actual update based on $scope.id

            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };
    }

);

var app = angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.MadeItHereMessage = 'We made it to the controller (first controller)';
    $scope.employees = {};
    $http.get('http://localhost:65315/api/employee').then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;
        $scope.Message = "OK";
    },
    function (err)
    {
        $scope.Message = "Call failed" + err.status + "  " + err.statusText;
    }
    );

});
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 AngularInit() calls? One from view and other in controller.

Comment: Because it looked to me, and my understanding is,  that function calls are not being performed. I could call the function from code to perform initialization, depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is loaded before you get the http data. So a solution is to display the template when the ressource is loaded with ng-if.

Can you try:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-if="employees && employees!={undefined}">
```

Comment: This turns out to be exactly the problem.  Good Job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the call to `window.setTimeout` with the `$timeout` service.

```
//window.setTimeout(function () {
//Use $timeout service
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.gotdata = true;
}, 1000);
```

The `$timeout` service is properly integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle. Changes to `$scope` made with `setTimeout` are not immediately seen by the AngularJS framework.

For more information, see [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: The only reason the timeout function was included to begin with was that I was trying things to try and determine if a timeout was occurring.  But good info to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to pass the $http into your "GetAllEmployees"-Function because it's already there!

Second, I would suggest to use the "$q" to save the response into a variable. [Check this out](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will try this as well.  The ng-if solution worked for me, and I didn't know about the $q function.  I knew that I didn't need to place the $http on the function, but was trying everything I could think of to get this to work.